# Is there a way to block all extensions on certain tabs on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-development, google-chrome-extensions

If you're using Chrome for web development and if you have some extensions running, when you check the Scripts tab of developer tools you'll see a bunch of javascript files used by extensions. Those files or better said extensions are not necessary during development process.

Do you know a way or maybe another extension to block all the extensions on particular tabs that you select? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an incognito window, Chrome disables the extensions by default in that mode.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing so before reading your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No; disabling the extension is applicable to Chrome in its entirety.

You will notice disabling an extension in a new instance will also propagate to the existing instances as the extensions themselves are relational to the browser; not the tabs.