# Hiding console errors from ad blockers

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

Using Chrome, I notice this message in devtools using any adblocker (ABP, uBlock, etc): `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

It makes sense why it shows up (the content is blocked by my client), but it clutters my console on every page, sometimes with many lines.

Is there a way to permanently filter these? Frankly I'm not sure why they show up at all (I did decide to filter it, after all).

I don't want to hide all network messages in case of a legit 404 (web dev)

Related but no fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr

This one is not related because the extension isn't throwing the error: [Chrome: Hide Extension Errors in JavaScript Console](https://superuser.com/questions/357354/chrome-hide-extension-errors-in-javascript-console?rq=1)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the filter box to remove these blocked requests:

```
-net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! Any chance to make this more easily togglable?